# How to search for gems inside of Ruby code, or where did Gem::RemoteInstaller go?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

In the Ruby Cookbook recipe 18.1, it is said that

```
Gem::RemoteInstaller.new.search('rails')
```

can search for gems on the remote site, defaulted to rubygems.org

but I tried in ruby 1.8.6, 1.8.7, and 1.9.2, and it all says

```
in `<main>': uninitialized constant Gem::RemoteInstaller (NameError)
```

I already tried

```
require 'rubygems'
```

and even

```
require 'rubygems/remote_installer'
```

Is there a new way to search using Gem inside of Ruby?

(please don't give answers such as `system("gem list rails")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gem::RemoteInstaller` has been removed from the rubygems since version 1.0.  This was a while ago.  If you are looking for the ability to set someone up with gems that they may not have, I would strongly suggest `bundler`  (actually I think all ruby projects should use it)  http://gembundler.com

OK, you can try:

```
 require 'rubygems'
 r = Gem::SpecFetcher.new
 r.suggest_gems_from_name('rails')
 => ["rails"]
```

Comment: still, the question is how to search it inside of Ruby, I think if tracing `gem list ___` it will lead to the calls...  even though it is not very abstracted way of doing things...

Comment: See edited answer I think this is what you are looking for.  This does approximate matching too.

Comment: it does approximate matching?  because if I type `r.suggest_gems_from_name('active')`, then activerecord won't show.  There is a `r.list` but that one shows everything, it seems, with a name and a GemSpec.  also strange is, `r.suggest_gems_from_name 'railss'` shows rails as well as railj, and `r.suggest_gems_from_name 'rai'` won't show rails.

Comment: This line will show all `rails` gems: `list = r.list(true); key = list.keys[0]; list[key].select {|i| i[0] == 'rails'}` if regular expresion is wanted, then `list = r.list(true); key = list.keys[0]; list[key].select {|i| i[0] =~ /authen/i}`